# Submit usando Ctrl + Enter ou Click no botão

Tags: javascript, jquery

Atualmente uso esse código para enviar minhas mensagens.

```
$('#chatEnvia').click(function() {
   $.post( "inc_chatEnvia.php", { acesso: "ok", msg: $("#chatEscrita").val() });
});
```

Gostaria de saber, como faço para quando for pressionado juntamente <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> seja executado o código para enviar as mensagens?

É importante que seja realizado o *submit*, tanto com o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> quanto com o pressionamento do botão.

Comment: Se a edição que fiz não corresponder ao que pretendia perguntar, por favor reverta-a ou diga que eu faço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que seja isso que precise:

```
$('#chatEnvia').click(function() {
   $.post( "inc_chatEnvia.php", { acesso: "ok", msg: $("#chatEscrita").val() });
});

$('#chatEscrita').keyup(function (e) {
   if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
      $('#chatEnvia').trigger('click');
   }
});
```

Comment: Só funciona o CTRL+Enter. Clicando no botão não.

Comment: Mas creio que você tenha que adicionar os dois eventos, o do click que já estava utilizando e o do keyup que eu passei

Comment: @Tiago vi que você alterou sua pergunta, você não quer utilizar o `$.post` é isso? Quer utilizar o submit do form nos dois eventos?

Comment: Isso, o `$.post` deve acontecer quando clicar no botão `#chatEnvia` ou apertar CTRL+ENTER.

Comment: Então @Tiago, se você colocar os dois métodos não funciona? Vou editar minha resposta pra ver se você entende.

Comment: Só funciona o CTRL+Enter. Clicando no botão não.

Comment: @Tiago veja se é isso que eu editei, caso não for, provavelmente não estou compreendendo direito o que você quer dizer, assim, vou abrir um chat contigo, aí fica mais fácil da gente se entender blz?

Comment: Bom dia. Obrigado pela ajuda. Testei hoje. Deu certo agora ;)

Comment: Que bom que ajudou, qualquer coisa estou a disposição, abraço!